# Creating an iOS passcode view with SwiftUI, how to hide a TextView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lockscreen

I am trying to imitate a lock screen of iOS in my own way with some basic code. However I do not understand how to properly hide an input textview. Now I am using an opacity modifier, but it does not seem to be the right solution. Could you please recommend me better options?

```swift
import SwiftUI
public struct PasscodeView: View {
        
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
    
    private let maxDigits: Int = 4
    private let userPasscode = "1234"
    
    @State var enteredPasscode: String = ""
    @FocusState var keyboardFocused: Bool
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertMessage = "Passcode is wrong, try again!"
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< maxDigits) {
                    ($0 + 1) > enteredPasscode.count ?
                    Image(systemName: "circle") :
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                }
            }
            .alert("Wrong Passcode", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            }
            
            
            TextField("Enter your passcode", text: $enteredPasscode)
                .opacity(0)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .focused($keyboardFocused)
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        keyboardFocused = true
                    }
                }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: enteredPasscode) { _ in
            guard enteredPasscode.count == maxDigits else { return }
            
            passcodeValidation()
        }
    }
    
    func passcodeValidation() {
        if enteredPasscode == userPasscode {
            viewModel.isUnlocked = true
            dismiss()
        } else {
            enteredPasscode = ""
            showAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Asperi, the code works well, I just wanted to know from experienced developers, if creating a view and then hiding it with an opacity modifier is a solution, that could be used in real projects or maybe there is an alternative option with no creation that TextView field at all?

Comment: You can use `SecureField()` which hides the input